# AWS Wildrydes example amplify build issue

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to work through:
https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/module-1/

I've gotten all the way through to the Amplify "save and build" button.  Pressing this yields no errors and I've been stuck on the app page (wildrydes-site).  There is a grey breathing bar under the app name (Does this mean it is doing something?) and my code repository (master) has no builds.  Within this section it says: "Your build is being queued. If your build has not started in over a minute, click the button below.".
Clicking "Run build" does not appear to do anything.  It has been this way for > 1hr.

AWS has generated no errors and is not giving me any useful feedback.  How long do deployments usually take?

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Tangential question: Failing with zero feedback is Not Good. Is this the general level of quality on AWS or is there a log somewhere I could have referenced?

In the end, with the added permissions, it worked quickly and with no problem.

FIX: Give the iam user and amplify role a stupid amount of permissions:

`{    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "UpdatedAmplifyAdminAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "amplify:CreateApp",
                "amplify:CreateBackendEnvironment",
                "amplify:GetApp",
                "amplify:CreateDeployment",
                "amplify:CreateDomainAssociation",
                "amplify:CreateWebHook",
                "amplify:GetBackendEnvironment",
                "amplify:ListApps",
                "amplify:ListBackendEnvironments",
                "amplify:CreateBranch",
                "amplify:GetBranch",
                "amplify:GenerateAccessLogs",
                "amplify:GetArtifactUrl",
                "amplify:GetBackendEnvironment",
                "amplify:GetDomainAssociation",
                "amplify:GetJob",
                "amplify:GetWebHook",
                "amplify:UpdateApp",
                "amplify:ListArtifacts",
                "amplify:ListBranches",
                "amplify:ListDomainAssociations",
                "amplify:ListJobs",
                "amplify:ListTagsForResource",
                "amplify:ListWebHooks",
                "amplify:DeleteBranch",
                "amplify:DeleteApp",
                "amplify:DeleteBackendEnvironment",
                "amplify:DeleteDomainAssociation",
                "amplify:DeleteJob",
                "amplify:DeleteWebHook",
                "amplify:StartDeployment",
                "amplify:StartJob",
                "amplify:StopJob",
                "amplify:TagResource",
                "amplify:UntagResource",
                "amplify:UpdateApp",
                "amplify:UpdateBranch",
                "amplify:UpdateDomainAssociation",
                "amplify:UpdateWebHook",
                "amplifybackend:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}`

From the site: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/1197